# Windows NT vs Win Server 2003/2008 for web hosting

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-nt

my web hoster uses windows nt as server + IIS 6 
I'm hosting an asp.net 3.5 web site and it... works great !
So my question is : why buying a win server 2003/2008 hosting instead an "old" NT if NT works great ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mean Windows NT. Windows NT is not a concrete OS it is family of OS which already includes mentioned by you Windows 2003 and Windows 2008 also.
And concerning IIS : if you will choose windows 2003 you will get IIS 6 and IIS 7 if you will choose windows 2008.
So what to choose depends on your needs.

Comment: You're right. I've discovered my hoster use Windows Server 2003 (but PHP info call it Win NT)